# fast jquery code to make a 3-column display HTML table

Tags: jquery, html-table, dom-manipulation

I have many pages where I get data entry forms such that one HTML row per field. Like:

```
<tr>
  <td>Label 1</td>
  <td>Field 1, could be text, select list or even fckeditor  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Label 2</td>
  <td>Field 2, could be text, select list or even fckeditor  </td>
</tr>
... and so on
```

I want to write a fast jquery each loop that traverses through entire table rows and convert it into a 6 column display so that my web page appears neat and make good use of space. And there are special fields marked with a class say, `<td class='special">Special field</td>` that should be kept out of this operation and should stay single row field (instead of 3 per row).

I've written the code and it works but it gives me "slow javascript" message when I've huge listboxes coming in the fields in many rows. Can somebody share a code snippet to achieve this faster w/o doing too much insertion/deletion in the DOM?

Comment: Why do this on the client. Get the server to output the _correct_ html.

Comment: @Raynos, I asked the same question, short answer is 42 (such pages). :-)

Comment: use a string manipulation tool to edit the file properly. Don't write some javascript to do this. Write some PERL to run on your server side code so that the table is formatted properly there.

Comment: I'm sorry I did not make it clear. We're talking 100+ fields in 50+ classic ASP pages each and visibility of each field (and its data content) is determined by zillion business rules and permission mappings. I need to balance between doing the perfect refactoring vs something as quick and dirty as this jquery hack I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you absolutely have to do it front-end, while I agree with the other commenter that you should do this on the backend... here's one way to do it:

http://jsfiddle.net/JHQEy/3/